# Gnome interface glitch after suspend

Tags: gnome, 20.04, graphics, gnome-terminal, interface

I get the following graphical glitch when I open my laptop after suspension:
[image]
It can be solved by restarting Gnome with [alt+f2 - r], but I came here to ask you if there's a definitive solution to this glitch

Comment: Did you found a different solution? This is also happening on Mint 20 XFCE

Comment: It cease to happen in my case after I renamed my computer's home folder for some reason. However, I do not recommend you to do that because some programs have difficulties reaching the files after you rename. (I mean, the solution is way worse than the problem itself so please DON'T DO IT)

Comment: Thanks, I'll stop using it for now. It is glitching my code editor, to see the context I need to restart and there are things that if I restart I'll spend a lot of time to setup... let's hope for a future fix ( :